# PostgreSQL date range query working locally, but not in production environment

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy

I'm working on an application that has, among other things, some order management functionality, and I've discovered a problem I believe is related to timezones.

**Background info**

The backend is written in Python and we are using Flask and SQLAlchemy. The database is PostgreSQL. We (both users and developers) are all in the same timezone (CET/CEST). The application in question is hosted on AWS, with servers in Ireland I believe.

**General description of problem**

When I retrieve orders and try to filter on a specific date range, orders from the first hour of the next day (outside the date range) is included in the result.

**Step-by-step**

1. The frontend sends a request to the Python backend with the date range in the query string.
2. A Flask blueprint receives the request, extracts the parameters in the query string, and calls function get_orders in the OrderService.
3. get_order creates a SQLAlchemy Query object and filters on the given parameters.

```
# Very simplified version of actual code
def get_orders(self, site_id, params):
    created_after = params.get('created_after')
    created_before = params.get('created_before')

    query = self.sess.query(Order) \
        .filter(Order.site_id == site_id)

    if created_after:
        dt = datetime.strptime(created_after, '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-%f')
        query = query.filter(Order.created_at > self._nor_to_utc_tz(dt))

    if created_before:
        dt = datetime.strptime(created_before, '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-%f')
        query = query.filter(Order.created_at < self._nor_to_utz_tz(dt))

    ...
    return result


def _nor_to_utc_tz(dt):
    # Incoming datetime is always the same timezone
    dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=tz.gettz('Europe/Oslo'))

    # All datetimes is stored as UTC on server
    dt = dt.astimezone(tz.gettz('UTC'))
    return dt
```

4. The query result is converted to a dict and returned to the Flask blueprint.
5. The blueprint returns the dict as JSON to the frontend.

**SQLAlchemy model template**

```
class Order(Base, ModelTemplate):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    ...
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    ...
```

**The results**

When testing this locally, everything works fine. I've made test orders on all hours of the day, and they are filtered on the correct date range.

The problem occurs in the production environment. Orders created right after midnight local time is included in the result for queries that should have been limited to orders created the day before.

**Example**

- Someone buys something on October 2 at 00:55 (UTC+2).
- The order is created and saved with timestamp 2019-10-01 22:55 (UTC+0).
- Later, someone wants to see all orders on October 2 and sends a request for all orders created after 2019-10-02 00:00:00 and before 2019-10-02 23:59:59.
- The backend converts those times to UTC+0 so that all orders created between 2019-10-01 22:00:00 and 2019-10-02 21:59:59 should be returned, but the aforementioned order is not.

**Theory**

My theory, based on nothing else than that I can't think of anything else that fits the pattern, is that postgres is converting the date range to the servers local time before filtering the result. I BELIEVE (or speculate) that the servers local time is UTC+1 (since Ireland), which fits with the result I get.

**What I've tried**

- Removing timezone information from datetime after converting from norwegian to UTC timezone, in case that tricked postgres into thinking the dt should be converted to local time.
- Adding timezone=True to the DateTime object in the SQLAlchemy model, to make it a timestamp with timezone in postgres, and then adding the norwegian timezone to the datetime used to filter the query (and not converting it to UTC+0, hoping postgres would do it).
- Being frustrated.

Comment: I know you said that you've tried using timestamp with time zone and regular timestamp, but which one were you using when you described all the above behavior?  Timestamp with time zone generally has fewer quirks and is usually the correct choice.

Comment: Regular timestamp was used when the above behavior occured. 

I guess I might've been on the right track when trying to change to timestamp with timezone. I will try some more.